# How to display custom ListFragment on MainActivity's tab using custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

Ok so I have a main activity with 3 tabs made by the standard Android template (ActionBar tabs with ViewPager). I have a `List<AppInfo>` which has some data I want to display on the 2nd tab in a ListView with 2 text fields per row.

The code below is organized as such:

my `ArrayAdapter` has the `List<AppInfo>`. It also uses app_info_row_layout.xml

my `ListFragment` sets its listadapter to my `ArrayAdapter`. It also uses list_fragment.xml

my `FragmentPagerAdapter` then creates my `ListFragment` in its `getItem()` method

Here is my ArrayAdapter class

```
public class AppInfoList extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo>{
    private List<AppInfo> list;
    private final Context context;

    public AppInfoList(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        list = // a list with objects is generated
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        AppInfo appInfo = list.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_info_row_layout, null, false);
        }

        // text field 1
        TextView appName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        appName.setText(appInfo.packageName);

        // text field 2
        TextView totalTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalTime);
        totalTime.setText( " minutes" ); // took out logic to make code shorter

        return convertView;
        }
}
```

the above uses a simple app_info_row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/appName"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/totalTime"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the custom ListFragment that's supposed to use the above ArrayAdapter and display its data in a ListView

```
public class AppInfoListFragment extends ListFragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AppInfoList appInfoAdapter = new AppInfoList(getActivity(), 0);
        setListAdapter(appInfoAdapter);
    }


}
```

using the following list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've extended the FragmentPagerAdapter and created the following

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment for 1st and 3rd tab

            // return different views/fragments here
            if(position == 1){
                if(appInfoListFragment == null)
                    appInfoListFragment = new AppInfoListFragment();
                return appInfoListFragment;
            }
            else
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
}
```

When I run the application, the 2nd tab is just blank instead of showing the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a custom adapter here since you are creating a entry with two textboxes each time.

Comment: I do have a custom ArrayAdapter. do you mean some other type of adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following setup:

Array Adapter class:

```
public class AppInfoList extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo>{
    private List<AppInfo> list;
    private final Context context;

    public AppInfoList(Context context, list<Appinfo>) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowLayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        AppInfo appInfo = list.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_info_row_layout, null, false);
        }

        // text field 1
        TextView appName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        appName.setText(appInfo.packageName);

        // text field 2
        TextView totalTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalTime);
        totalTime.setText( " minutes" ); // took out logic to make code shorter

        return convertView;
        }
}
```

All other classes seem to be fine. For your reference, I used the following tutorial to [help me](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown).

Comment: Please consider upvoting this answer if it has helped you :)